# Background image for ContentView (SwiftUI) not subviews but with proper scrolling behavior

Tags: swiftui

How do we get a background image for the ContentView but not its subviews AND retain the behavior of scrollable content disappearing under the NavBar?

I found that if I added the background as a modifier to a List or ScrollView, it didn't change the background on subviews (ex. DetailView) but scrollable content no longer disappeared under the navbar and the NavBar title stayed in place (see pic #2).  But if I modified the NavigationView, it restored the behavior of scrollable content disappearing under the navbar (see pic #3) but it also changed the background on all subviews (see pic #4)

I tried a ZStack with Image("MoonPhoto") and then the List

But mostly I tried different placements of this ViewModifier struct:

```
struct BackgroundImage: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .opacity(0.8)
            .background(Image("history-in-hd-e5eDHbmHprg-unsplash")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill())
    }
}
```

And here is the main body of ContentView:

```
     var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(missions) { mission in
                NavigationLink(destination: MissionView(mission: mission, astronauts: self.astronauts))
                {
                    Image(mission.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(mission.displayName)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(self.showCrew ? self.crewList(mission: mission) : mission.formattedLaunchDate)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Moonshot")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Moonshot")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(self.showCrew ? "Show Launch date" : "Show crew") {
                    self.showCrew.toggle()
                }
            )
            .modifier(BackgroundImage()) //Modifying List
        } //If you move the above modifier here, the image shows an all subviews too
    }
}
```

[image: screenshots 1 and 2]

[image: screenshots 3 and 4]

Comment: I cannot answer your question now. But I suggest you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128547/swiftui-list-color-background , before your further search.

Comment: That would be great if you can take a look. I tried different things from the article you linked to but they don't seem to be the answer. Even one of their answers shows the need for the navbar - otherwise scrolling content goes past the safe area and doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major issue as I observe is about .large DisplayMode for navigationBarTitle modifier. I've found a solution appropriate for me, but still it's like a workaround. Anyway, you can consider it as a temporary solution.

*The main idea is to wrap List in VStack and use .inline display mode.* Hope, this would help somehow.

Here how it looks (works for Dark Mode as well)

[image: list with background]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BackgroundImage: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .opacity(0.8)
            .background(Image("history-in-hd-e5eDHbmHprg-unsplash")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill())
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List (1...20, id: \.self) { value in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details \(value)")) {
                        Text("\(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .modifier(BackgroundImage())
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works with only one small (but acceptable to me) tradeoff: The App title starts inline instead of animating to that position upon scrolling.