# Make NavigationView background to transparent in swiftUI (not navigationbar)

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

My NavigationView is inside an Image . Because of the white background of NavigationView , the image is not visible .

• Adding opacity to navigationView background color property is not working in swiftui

• Only Way I found is to make NavigationView Opacity value to zero . But child views are inherited by the same opacity value and gone hidden.

Is there any way to clear navigationView Background Or is there any way to add opacity to parent without affecting child views

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58716435/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Nop. I tried it . Actually my NavigationView is inside an Image . what I want is to show the image behind navigationView