# Why background color of List is different while presenting view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am implementing List in Presented view (AddItemView). I want background color same as List in any view.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var showAddItemView: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<9, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Row \(i)")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button("Add") {
                    showAddItemView.toggle()
                })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddItemView) {
                AddItemView()
            }    
        }
    }
}

struct AddItemView: View {
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<9, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Row \(i)")
            }.background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Add Item View", displayMode: .inline)    
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is creating simple List with InsetGroupedListStyle. But background colour is different while Presenting view (AddItemView in my case).

I have already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427518/7084910

How to set background color of List in presented view as in any normal list. Red/Yellow/Green can set to List, "BUT" I want same as normal list in HomeView that will work in light & dark mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is Presented View? Would you show code?

Comment: @Asperi, I have update the question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(0..<9, id: \.self) { i in
            Text("Row \(i)")
        }
        .colorMultiply(Color.red)

    }
}
```

Comment: Red, Yellow, Green, etc are working with init() { .clear }. But I want same as which is in HomeView.

Comment: pick the same color with rgb values and use it. what issue are you still facing with ans?

Comment: For light and dark mode. systemGroupedBackground is perfect for both. I want without condition of color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

They think it is better visual representation for `.sheet` (probably to make it more determinable)...

**SwiftUI 2.0**

The `.fullScreenCover` gives what you want. Alternate is to present `AddItemView` manually using some transition.

[image: demo]

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    Button("Add") {
        showAddItemView.toggle()
    })
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showAddItemView) {
    AddItemView()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. but in my case, HomeView is already fullScreenCover.