# SwiftUI: SearchBar moving out of bound when the List is too long

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've implemented a search bar in my app inside a custom header. Beneath the search bar I have added a false `List` with 100 rows that is intended to show search results.

The problem that I'm facing is:

- when the list appears, the search bar moves out of bounds. When I add a top padding of 400px, the search bar comes back to bounds.  [Link to video 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlkMU.gif)

The next two are a bit out of topic.

- When the keyboard is on screen, the last few rows of the list are not visible. How to fix it? [Link to video 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzczT.gif)
- How to set a background color for a `List`? I haven't been able to figure that out. (listRowBackground modifier isn't working as suggested by an article I read.)

I'm using Xcode 12.0 beta 6.

```
let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

struct SearchBarView: View {
    @Binding var search: String
    @Binding var searchSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(text: $search, isFirstResponder: true)
                .modifier(SearchBarTextFieldStyle(search: $search))

            if !search.isEmpty {
                  List(1..<100) { i in
                      Text("Hello \(i)")
                  }.frame(width: screen.width)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: screen.width, height: !search.isEmpty ? screen.height : 40)
        .background(Color("ThemeColor"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the list appears, the search bar moves out of bounds. When I add
> a top padding of 400px, the search bar comes back to bounds.

The issue is that everything is placed in one `VStack`. So when search is not empty anymore the `TextField` shares the space provided to it with the `List`.

Place the `TextField` in a separate Stack like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var search: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        // Everything wrapped in one Stack
        VStack() {
            
            // Separate Stack for the TextField 
            HStack() {
                TextField("Title", text: self.$search)
            }.padding()
            
            // One Stack for the content
            VStack {
                if !search.isEmpty {
                      List(1..<100) { i in
                          Text("Hello \(i)")
                      }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .background(Color.red)
            
            Spacer() // So that the TextField is also on top when no content is displayed 
        }
    }
}
```

> When the keyboard is on screen, the last few rows of the list are not
> visible. How to fix it?

Add a padding to the bottom of the list but I'd recommend implementing the solution of this: [Move TextField up when the keyboard has appeared in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftui/56497673#56497673)

E.g. with padding:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var search: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            
            HStack() {
                TextField("Title", text: self.$search)
            }.padding()
            
            VStack {
                if !search.isEmpty {
                    List(1..<100) { i in
                        Text("Hello \(i)")
                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                        .padding(.bottom, 300) // here padding
                }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

> How to set a background color for a List? I haven't been able to
> figure that out. (listRowBackground modifier isn't working as
> suggested by an article I read.)

This question has also already been answered here:
[SwiftUI List color background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128547/swiftui-list-color-background)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Separating the `TextField` and `List` doesn't solve the issue as both have same parent container as before. However, I did a work around and  decreased the parents height with the keyboard height(as suggested by you) and added a `Spacer`. This solved 2 problems, bringing the search bar to bounds and unhiding rows from the `List`. The link you directed me for the `List` background color didn't work out for me. Maybe because I couldn't interpret it well, as there is no explanation given in the solution.

Comment: As you can see on my first example the ```TextField``` and ```List``` also share a parent . The ```Spacer``` is required to keep the ```TextField``` on top when no ```List``` is there. I had just written it in the comments of the code but not mentioned it. The code I provided is working for me under iOS 13.5.1. But glad you could solve it

Comment: Hey! sorry for the late reply :'( Unfortunately I'm not using iOS 13 on my device, so i can't comment on it. In iOS 14 it doesn't seem to work. Anyways thanks for your answer. Appreciate it.