# I applied .onAppear () {UITableView.appearance (). BackgroundColor = UIColor.clear}, but it doesn't make the screen transparent

Tags: swiftui, alpha

```
**
Hello everybody.
    i applied the above indicator, but the image but i still see only about half screen. the bottom remains gray. I applied ".onAppear () {
```

UITableView.appearance (). BackgroundColor = UIColor.clear} "because I would like to have transparency and see the whole image below and leave only the part of the list highlighted, but under the list I have only the gray screen and not the image. Basically no transparencies are applied through .

'''

```
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    VStack {  // DEFINISCO IL NEW TASK
                        VStack(spacing: 16) {
                            TextField("New Task", text: $task)
                                .padding()
                                .background(
                                    Color(UIColor.systemGray6)
                                )
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                addItem()
                            }, label: {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("SAVE")
                                Spacer()
                            })
                            .disabled(isButtonDisabled)
                            .padding()
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(isButtonDisabled ? Color.gray : Color.pink)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            
                        } //: VSTACK
                        .padding()
                        
                        List {
                            ForEach(items) { item in
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text(item.task ?? "")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        
                                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                                            .font(.footnote)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    
                                    }
    }
                            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                        } //: LIST
                        
                        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                        .shadow(color: Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0,opacity: 0.3),
                    radius: 12)
                        .padding(.vertical, 0)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 640)
                    } //: VSTACK
                }  //: ZSTACK
                .onAppear() {
                    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }
                
                .navigationTitle("Daily Tasks")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        EditButton()
                    }
    } //: TOOLBAR
                .background(
                    BackgroundImageView()
                )
                .background(
                    backgroundGradient.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                )
                Text("Select an item")
    
            } //: NAVIGATION VIEW
     }
```

Comment: Different iOS  versions, different behaviors. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128547/swiftui-list-color-background)

Comment: i see, but I don't understand.

Comment: in ios16 ok, but in ios15 it's not clear and don't work.